# why can't I put a conditional statement in file to set global variable values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to define a number of variables that I will use in view controllers to set font size depending on whether the user is on an iphone or an ipad. So far I can define, say, a global float no problem. However, I am not able to include any conditional statements in my file. This works fine:

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface GlobalDeclarations : NSObject
extern float MyGlobalVariable;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "GlobalDeclarations.h"
@implementation GlobalDeclarations
float MyGlobalVariable = 0.0f;
@end
```

But I cannot modify my .m file to include any if statement at all - I always get the same error:

```
"expected idenitifer or ')'
```

For example, this version of the .m file produces the above error:

```
#import "GlobalDeclarations.h"
@implementation GlobalDeclarations
float MyGlobalVariable = 0.0f;
if(MyGlobalVariable > 2.0f)
{ 
   NSLog(@"inside if statement");
}

@end
```

I get the error even if I just write something like if(TRUE)...

How can I conditionally define globals in an attachment like this? What is wrong with the if-statement? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to put your logic inside some method or function.

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you. How/where should I then call that function?

Comment: You can only have compile-time constants added in the manner you're asking. For conditional logic you can use pre-compiler directives. See this other [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059708/defining-a-constant-in-objective-c).. I think

Comment: That's specific to your app's requirements.  When do you want it to execute?

Comment: (off topic) also, @SunnysideProductions as in, sunnyside, ny? 45th street?

Comment: @LouisTur Yes, I'm at 48th and Skillman.

Comment: @PhillipMills I am taking your suggestion and implementing a function I call from the including custom view controllers. Not as minimal codewise as I was hoping, but that's life. Thank you!

Comment: @SunnysideProductions oh nice! I'm very close by, and I used to walk by S.Productions every day. Send me an email to the address in my profile if you'd ever like to bounce some code off each other

Answer (score 0):

For variables you can only have declarations and limited initialisation expressions as the file level. If you need more complex initialisation you must put the code in a method, and Objective-C supports the method `+ initialize` for doing class-wide setup.

Rewrite your code as:

```
#import "GlobalDeclarations.h"

@implementation GlobalDeclarations

float MyGlobalVariable = 0.0f;

+ initialize
{
   if(MyGlobalVariable < 2.0f)
   { 
      NSLog(@"inside if statement");
   }
}

@end
```

The `+ initialize` method will get called before the first use of the class.

Note: for more obscure situations there is also a `+ load` method which gets called even earlier than `+ initialize`, and there are attributes you can use to mark any function to be called in a similar way.